# Async/await, ThreadPool and SetApartmentState

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, com, async-await

I'd like to use `await Task.Run(DoWork)`, to do some repetitive single-threaded computational work on ThreadPool. The problem is, I need to use STA COM objects inside `DoWork`, so I guess I cannot use ThreadPool because I cannot alter the apartment state of a pool thread.

How can I still use `async`/`await` in this scenario? Creating my own pool of STA threads with a custom task scheduler sounds like an excessive work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stephen Toub has already written an [`StaTaskScheduler`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-5-stataskscheduler/) <sup>*([archive](https://archive.vn/wip/CKmnM))*</sup>; I recommend you use that.

You can then construct a `TaskFactory` using that `TaskScheduler`. There is no equivalent to `Task.Run` on the `TaskFactory` type but you can easily create one [using `StartNew` and `Unwrap`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).