# StaTaskScheduler and await continuation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm using Stephen Toub's [`StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx) for the reason described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648620/async-await-threadpool-and-setapartmentstate).

As far as I understand, task scheduling is the responsibility of Task Scheduler, while `await` continuation is the responsibility of Synchronization Context (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Now I want to use `await` inside my task code running on one of the STA threads, created by `StaTaskScheduler`. Should I install a custom Synchronization Context, to make sure the code execution will be continued on the *same* STA thread after `await`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cover the `await` behavior in my [intro to `async` blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

By default, `await` will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` *unless it is `null`*, in which case it will capture the current `TaskScheduler`.

So, the answer is no, you do not need to install a custom `SynchronizationContext`. When used inside a task executed by `StaTaskScheduler`, `await` will by default capture that task scheduler and resume on another task executed by that `StaTaskScheduler`.

Note that `StaTaskScheduler` does maintain a *collection* of STA threads, and the continuation may execute on any of those threads. If this is unacceptable, you'll need to limit the `StaTaskScheduler` to a single thread (by passing `1` to its constructor).

Comment: Thanks Stephen again for the comprehensive answer, your blog is a must-read. I've got one more question. I would still like to keep a pool of STA threads, but I'd like to have thread affinity for each task code, when an STA thread for it has been allocated, until the work is finished. Can this still be done without custom `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: That can't be solved at the `SynchronizationContext` level. When you install a `SynchronizationContext`, you're really saying that you control the core loop of that thread. But in this case you don't; the core loop is in `StaTaskScheduler`, and it doesn't honor thread affinity. The cleanest solution in your case AFAIK is to write your own type that maintains a pool of `StaTaskScheduler`s, each containing a single thread.

Comment: @avo: On second thought, an easier solution may be to use [my `AsyncContext`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext) *within* the (higher-level) tasks queued to the `StaTaskScheduler`. `AsyncContext.Run` will install a thread-affine `SynchronizationContext` and wait until all `async` methods complete before returning. This may be not quite what you want (the STA thread will be *blocked* until each operation completes), but it would be easier than maintaining a pool of `StaTaskScheduler`s.

Comment: BTW, `AsyncContext.Run` can install a `SynchronizationContext` because it does provide its own (temporary) core loop.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'll consider borrowing  your `AsyncContext`, thank you @StephenCleary.